# How to retrieve all files from dropbox version history?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have a script that uploads data to Dropbox every hour. Unfortunately, I made a mistake and the script has been overwriting the existing file with each new upload. Consequently, I only have one data file in my Dropbox, which is continuously replaced with a new version.

Fortunately, I've discovered that Dropbox maintains a version history for all changes to this file. As the script has been uploading new data every hour, there have been 24 new entries per day, accumulating to thousands over the past six months.

I'm looking for a more efficient solution to retrieve these past versions. Is there a way to download all these versions using a script or some online tool, instead of manually downloading each one from the Dropbox interface?

I try to use python with selenium but because I am using college account so it need duo Two-Factor Authentication when login which is tricky.

I think dropbox API may be helpful but I didn't find any useful information in its documents.

Comment: According to [this thread](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/How-could-I-get-the-all-revisions-of-one-file-with-API-v2/td-p/247306), the v2 API has a limit on how many past revisions of a file you may access. The thread also mentions the v1 API, but that has been retired for years. I suspect Selenium may be your only option.

Comment: @Nick ODell, thanks. I will try selenium again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nick mentioned in the comments, the Dropbox API does offer the ability to list file revisions using [/2/files/list_revisions](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_revisions), however that only supports listing up to 100 revisions unfortunately. I'll pass this along as a feature request for support for listing any number of revisions, but I can't promise if or when that might be implemented.

For reference, to download the file content for a particular revision, you would use [/2/files/download](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download) and pass the `rev:` value in the `path` parameter.

By the way, those are links to the documentation for the HTTPS endpoints themselves, but we recommend using one of [the official SDKs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation#sdks) if possible. Those have corresponding native methods for the HTTPS endpoints.